# Need help in debugging: "The object (quote test-divisor), ...is not an identifier."

Tags: scheme

I am a beginner of scheme.

I wrote below simple procedure for finding divisor, and tried to load it into scheme intepreter, but only get a simple warning without line number. May I know what went wrong? Thanks.

```
;            Loading "test_euler3.scm"...
;The object (quote test-divisor), passed as an argument to identifier->symbol, is not an identifier.
(define (find-divisor' test-divisor n)
  (cond ((= test-divisor 1)
     1)
    ((divides? n test-divisor)
     test-divisor)
    (else
     (find-divisor' (- test-divisor 1) n))))
```

Comment: try deleting the quote in the procedures name `test-divisor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Rptx's comment says, `find-divisor'` is not a valid identifier, since `'` is not a valid identifier character. If you really want to use it, you must escape the identifier, using something like `|find-divisor'|`.

But it's better just to stick to characters that are valid for use with identifiers. Heck, just use a smart quote (e.g., `find-divisor’`) or prime (e.g., `find-divisor′`), if you want something that *looks* like `find-divisor'`. I won't vouch for the readability of any code that uses smart quotes, though. :-P

Comment: thanks. I may have mixed the naming convention with Haskell which allows for single quote. Let me test it out.

Comment: Indeed. Without that single quote everything went mellifluous.